# Parse file name separated by underlines name with named captured groups when a part of it contains the separator

Tags: regex

I would like to mention that this is my first attempt of working with named groups.

I have to parse these name files and, for convenience capture those groups to later extract the values.

22203_17053180_2020-05-13_TRAN.LET_002.pdf

22203_17053180_2020-05-13_AP_DK_M_002.pdf

22203_17053180_2020-05-13_AP_DK_M.pdf

I have some sort of an idea here and this is my first try ..

`(?P<appcorresp>\d{5})[_](?P<appnumber>\d{8})[_](?P<date>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})`

[image]

But now I need to capture the next group which would we could call the `<doctype>` group and it could either be

`TRAN.LET` or `AP_DK_M`

and the part with `_002` can be present or not.

If `_002` is there, it would be needed. Otherwise the entire regex should still be fine.

**Later edit:**

That `<doctype>` group is defined between the underline of the date and, if present, the underline of that 002 stuff, which by the way is a random stuff, it will just be something like a \d{3} I suppose.

Comment: (?P<appcorresp>\d{5})[_](?P<appnumber>\d{8})[_](?P<date>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})_(?P<doctype>(?:TRAN\.LET|AP_DK_M)(?:_002)?)\.pdf

Comment: So, just add `_(?P<doctype>.*?)\.\w+$` at the end of your regex.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I tried that but then my doctype would be TRAN.LET_002 and .. as mentioned I only need something like  TRAN.LET or AP_DK_M, something before the date and the _002 which by the way is _002 in this case, but it will have a random value. I will update my question.

Comment: Yes, you need to update because you wrote ***If _002 is there, it would be needed.*** So, you need to add `_(?P<doctype>.*?)(?:_\d+)?\.\w+$`. See https://regex101.com/r/Xn9dNy/1

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Just did, thanks and sorry for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
^(?P<appcorresp>\d{5})_(?P<appnumber>\d{8})_(?P<date>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})_(?P<doctype>.*?)(?:_\d+)?\.\w+$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JS9gWz/1).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?P<appcorresp>\d{5})` - Group "appcorresp": five digits
- `_` - an underscore
- `(?P<appnumber>\d{8})` - Group "appnumber": eight digits
- `_` - an underscore
- `(?P<date>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})` - Group "date": four digits, `-`, two digits, `-` and two digits
- `_` - an underscore
- `(?P<doctype>.*?)` - Group "doctype": any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `(?:_\d+)?` - an optional sequence of `_` and one or more digits
- `\.` - a dot
- `\w+` - one or more word chars
- `$` - end of string.